# PHP 'exec' command doesn't properly work with 'awk' command

Tags: php, linux, awk, exec

I am using following php code:

```
<?php 
    exec ("awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' /var/log/apache2/forensic_log.log /var/log/apache2/access.log | cut -d'|' -f1,3- > i/content/other/LOG_FILE.log"); 
?>
```

It compares to log files, concatenate content if log ids match and output it to the LOG_FILE.log. As a result I should have something similar in LOG_FILE.log

```
[14/May/2018:06:37:07 +0300]|HEAD /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0|Host:host.com|Connection:close
```

This code worked fine for a long time, but now it seems that it fails somewhere because the LOG_FILE.log is blank.

1. I checked paths mentioned in the script - they are correct.
2. Tried script locally using both log files - it works and produces expected output to LOG_FILE.log
3. It seems that the issue occurred when we updated apache2 to 'Apache/2.4.34'
4. Adding permissions to the files:
   LOG_FILE.log - 777
   File where the PHP code is executed - 664 
   access.log - 640 
   forensic_log.log - 640

Adding simplified code:

```
<?php
  $output=exec("awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' /var/log/apache2/forensic_log.log /var/log/apache2/access.log"); 
  echo $output;
?>
```

This code doesn't echo anything.

I am sorry for such messy question but I am not the author of the code and not familiar with PHP, but still I have to somehow deal with this problem.

Comment: Are the awk variables "$0", "$1" and "$2" getting substituted by PHP before the awk command is executed?

Comment: Try to use `$output` and `$return_var` values of the exec function to debug this: `string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`. (Also you could simply replace `exec` with `echo` to confirm that PHP doesn't mess up the command text.)

Comment: For convenience you could try to debug the AWK command first to ensure that it produces non-empty output: `exec ("awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' /var/log/apache2/forensic_log.log /var/log/apache2/access.log", $output, $return_var);`

Comment: I tried to simplify the code and it seems that output of the command is blank: `$output=exec("awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' /var/log/apache2/forensic_log.log /var/log/apache2/access.log"); 
echo $output;` - this command doesn't echo anything.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I have updated description with simplified code as you suggested, it echoes nothing, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @AndreyNazarov, please, post samples of your `access.log` and `forensic_log.log` files.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a cause of the issue and solved it. The issue didn't relate to 'awk' command, sorry for that. The issue was in permissions to apache log files, once I have fixed it the origin code started producing expected output.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.